# Load content in div from external pages in same website

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I try to load in content to a div in Intex based on choice in a select box. It dont work so something is wrong. I made an example of four pages to show basicly how it is:

```
Index.html
one.html
two.html
three.html
```

In Index I have a select element with ID "selectchoice":

```
<select id="selectchoice>
<option>Select a choice</option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
```

I also have a div in Index with id "get_content":

```
<div id="get_content"></div>
```

When I change the select element to option 1 or 2 or 3 I want to load one.html or two.html or three.html into the div get_content.

Then I place this code in the header if Index.html, after the jQuery-file link.

```
<script>
$("#selectchoice").change(function(){
    $("#get_content").load("");
    $("#get_content").load("one.html");
    $("#get_content").load("two.html");
    $("#get_content").load("three.html");
});
```

And then I run the site (on a server with other load-scripts thats works on the same site), but its not working. What is wrong? :/

Kinda new to scrips and programming so do not be suprised if there is any standard error.

Anybody finding the error?

Comment: When you say it is not working, what do you mean exactly? Is it always loading three.html or is it not loading anything ever?

Comment: <select id="selectchoice> -> <select id="selectchoice">

Comment: Nothings loads into the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `select` tag is not closed properly. Add `"` after your id to close the id attribute.
It'll then look like this:

`<select id="selectchoice">` ...

Try replacing your javascript with this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#selectchoice").change(function(){

        var selectedOption = $('#selectchoice :selected').val();
        $containerDiv = $('#get_content');
        $containerDiv.html("");

        switch (selectedOption)
        {
            case "1": 
                $containerDiv.load( "one.html" );
                break;

            case "2":
                $containerDiv.load( "two.html" );
                break;

            case "3":
                $containerDiv.load( "three.html" );
                break;

            default:
                $containerDiv.load( "whatever.html" );
                break;
       }

        return true;
    });​
});
```

`$(document).ready(...)` makes the code execute once the page is loaded, which means it'll bind the function to the onChange event right when you will load the page, while before it wouldn't execute the script since it wasn't called anywhere.

This code respects most of the [Object Calisthenics practices](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2374-Object-Calisthenics-In-JavaScript-An-Introduction.htm). I cut myself some loose since it is only a small snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the code but I think there is some other problem then the script, se my last post.

Comment: @Wobot Try changing the `.load(...);` methods for `.html("1");` (and other numbers) to see if the div writes numbers onChange.

Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/G4yRx/

Comment: I mean take a look at this:  http://jsfiddle.net/G4yRx
This is just to see if something is wrong with the content you are trying to load. I will edit my answer in a second, consider taking a look at it (I may have found what's wrong).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time.

Now its clear that its not your script thats the error becuse I tested that code from jsfiddle-link as it is on my page and the text dont show up when browse the alternatives.

Its like something is wrong with the jQuery or something, anyways I deleted all other scripts in the page also without no better results.

I am kinda new in coding so do you maybe have any further tips for finding the error?

Comment: Try using Google Chrome and opening the page again. Once it's opened, Press `F12` to open up Webkit Inspector and head over to the **console** tab. Then select an option in your `select` box. Is there any errors showing up in the console? (You can do the same thing with Firefox's firebug console). Also doublecheck that your loading html pages are in the same folder and correctly linked.

Comment: The consol in chrome found nothing wrong. The consol in Firefox only found some smal css-problems (backgrounds, radius etc of some buttons etc). No JS errors in chrome or firefox. The jquery link is <script src="JS/jquery-1.8.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and it make 3-4 others scripts (incl one load script) on the same page work. Can it possible be something with the server? Using WAMP.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21396/discussion-between-wobot-and-ghillied)

Answer (score 3):

first the select tag's id attribute should be closed, and the your javascript function should be optiomized. Something like

```
<script>
$("#selectchoice").change(function(){
    var page = this.selectedIndex;
    if(page == 1) { 
       $("#get_content").load("one.html");
       return;
    }
    else if(page == 2) {
      $("#get_content").load("two.html");
      return;
   }
   ....  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I think there is some other problem then the script, se my last post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){ // do it after page load
   $("#selectchoice").change(function(e){
     if(e.target.value=="select a choice"){ // you can use switch instead of if
       $("#get_content").load("");
     }else if(e.target.value=="1"){
       $("#get_content").load("one.html");
     }
     //....
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I think there is some other problem then the script, se my last post.